# Circumventing query page size limitations

Tags: google-app-maker

In the [Project Tracker template](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/) there is a feature where statistics for a certain project's items are displayed. You can filter the project items, but the statistics will only show those statistics for all the project items, i.e. the filters do not affect the statistics.

I would like to add the feature of filters affecting those statistics in a similar implementation of mine. My current solution passes the keys of those project items (affected by filters, too) to a calculated data source, which then calculates the statistics using those item keys, essentially applying the filters used in the page.

My issue is that my calculations are restricted by the query page size. For example, if I apply filters that limit the number of items to 15 records, but the page size is 10 records, I will only have statistics of those first 10 items, which is not useful. I'd need to have the statistics on all the records that are left after filtering.

One way to solve this would be to get rid of the query page size and leave it at 0. However, similarly to the Project Tracker template, I'm displaying the project items on the page in a table, and if I do that, the page becomes too heavy.

How can I circumvent the query page size? I'm thinking I could

- limit the items displayed in the page by some other way than query page size (i.e. hiding items from the UI)
- use a different datasource for the statistics, but in some way copying the filters used in the datasource that is displaying the project items

Both of these ways I could think of, I can't seem to implement. I don't know how I could hide items from the UI to make it less heavy, as query page size pretty much does it. I have also tried copying the filters from a datasource to a similar one, but that does not seem to work.

EDIT: I might have come up with a way to solve this myself, but I still need to implement it. Now I'm using the page size restricted Items Ds to apply the filters on, and the statistics are build from this data source. If instead, I use a non-restricted Ds called AllItems, and apply the filters on it, and then pass the item keys to a page size restricted Ds (to show the items in UI) AND to a calculated Ds (for the stats). Will make a response once I've verified it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself.

To produce (refreshable) statistics subject to filtering but not restricted by page size, I used the following datasource structure:

[image]

In this structure, the filters practically flow to the data sources below, as they are passed the ItemKeys that fit the filter. What this completes is that my Statistics (used in piegraphs etc.) can be filtered dynamically and account for all the records that fit the filter, while the UI does not get crowded over too many records, as the data source used in UI has a query page size limitation.